# I try to update list value inside my function, but it doesnt update any value

Tags: python, list

```
def find_ana(s):
    word_dict, number, pointer = {}, {}, {}
    a = list(set(s))
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        word_dict[a[i]] = []
        number[a[i]] = 0
        pointer[a[i]] = 0

    for i in range(len(s)):
        word_dict[s[i]].append(i)
        number[s[i]] += 1
        pointer[s[i]] += 1
        answer.append("c")
    sssss = max(number, key=number.get)
    if number[sssss] > len(s):
        answer = "IMPOSSIBLE"
        return answer
    else:
        while len(number) != 0:
            m = max(number, key=number.get)

            number_m = number[m]
            number.pop(m, None)
            n = min(pointer, key=pointer.get)
            number_n = word_dict[n]
            pointer.pop(n, None)

            while number_m != 0:
                ba = number_n.pop()
                answer[ba] = m
                number_m = number_m - 1
                if len(number_n) == 0:
                    n = min(pointer, key=pointer.get)
                    pointer.pop(n, None)
                    number_n = word_dict[n]
                elif number_m == 0 and len(number_n) != 0:
                    pointer[n] = len(number_n)
        return answer
```

Hello, this is my code to find out a string with no redundant alphabet in any position. Here inside I update pointer[b]=len(number_n) but it doesnt change at all. could you tell me how to update it so I can get the answer? it is like I put the word string and want to get a list of alphabets that are arranged with new order s.t. s[I]!=answer[I].
For example I put ['s','t','a','r','t'] and want to get ['t','s','t','a','r'], but I only got ['c','c','c','c','c']

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and output to show what this function is trying to achieve?

Comment: for example I put s='start' and try to get a dictionary that will give me {'s':[1],'t':[0,2],'a':[3'],'r':[4]}

Comment: actually I put s='start' and tried to get answer=['t','s','t','a','r'] list but list update answer[I]='a' didnt work so I tried to update dictionary..and again it didnt update dictionary..

Comment: @dbdbdbdb please [edit] your question and add that information there, could you also explain what you want to do if the string contains a redundant character? do you just want to find whether a string has any duplicate chars? do you want to get the duplicate chars? or what?

Comment: I changed my code and tried to explain what I want to get..but not sure whether this clarifies my intention.

Comment: Like @user2390182 mentioned, provide a sample input, the expected output and the actual output you are getting with your code right now, and explain how the actual output is different from the expected output.

Comment: done and done..now is everything clear?

Comment: can you explain how you got _c_ from a word that doesn't contain any _c_? it is still unclear what you want to achieve. what do you mean by _list of alphabets that are arranged with new order_? what _new order_? how is it formed?

Comment: the thing is at first I just randomly fill the list with 'c' so that the answer list has entry and I can use the same index. new order s.t. s[I]!=answer[I] so each alphabet in the list is different from the original one

Comment: The code you've pasted crashes on the first line of the function: `word_dict, number, pointer = {}, {}, {}, {}` - `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`.

Comment: oops I need to reduce one {}...ill do that now

Comment: You might also consider adding comments that would help a reader walk through your algorithm here. It doesn't help that there's a variable called `sssss`, for instance...

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Sorry about that. that is also random. If the most frequent alphabet occurs more than half of the time, then there is no such arrangement, so I just try to test it with random name variable 'sssss'

Comment: In any case, have you tried debugging with e.g. just `print()`s? Running your code, I never get a case where `number_m` would be zero, so the inner loop where you'd modify `answer` is never reached.

Comment: I just ran the code by parts and did get updates, but if I ran the function all I got was ccccc..oh and I edited the code it is number_m!=0...oh my gosh..maybe that part was wrong...

Comment: YES...that part was wrong. I am really sorry ...

Comment: still in the last part the dictionary update pointer[n]=len(number_n) is not implemented..

Comment: With your current code and the string `"start"`, I get `n = min(pointer, key=pointer.get)` - `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`. I would say that your algorithm here is faulty.

Comment: yes yes I am getting it fixed! thank you for helping me. The thing is I think using elements from the top and filling in from the bottom may crash at the middle so I just try using elements from the top and filling in from the next of the top.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want a function that shuffles a given string in a way that there are no matching characters (same letter in the same position) as in the original word.

One way to do that would be

```
import random


def shuffle_word(word, max_attempts=1000):
    letters = list(word)
    for attempt in range(max_attempts):
        random.shuffle(letters)
        new_word = "".join(letters)
        if not any(a == b for (a, b) in zip(word, new_word)):
            return new_word
    raise RuntimeError("Could not find a suitable variation")


print(shuffle_word("start"))
```

and to get *all* the permutations that match this rule,

```
import itertools

def get_word_variations(word):
    letters = tuple(word)
    for combo in itertools.permutations(letters):
        if not any(a == b for (a, b) in zip(letters, combo)):
            yield "".join(combo)
```

Comment: yes that is what I wanted. but I don't need an answer from other people. I want to know what I did wrong so I can improve my code...

Comment: I tried to get the most frequent alphabet and tried to fill from the least redundant alphabet to find out the answer and I think my logic is right..but cannot update the list, which bothers me to death. sigh.